# Braiding (up to equivalence?)

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, braidings

I am slightly confused by the definition of a braiding in a monoidal category. It says that it is a natural isomorphism $c_{X,Y}\colon X\otimes Y\to Y\otimes X$. If I understand this correctly, this means that taking any $f\colon X\to X'$, $g\colon Y\to Y'$, we must have
$$c_{X',Y'}(f\otimes g)=(f\otimes g)c_{X,Y}.$$

My question is: What if I find a class of isomorphisms $c_{X,Y}$ such that the above equation holds up to a monoidal autoequivalence. That is, suppose we have a monoidal equivalence $F\colon C\to C$ and
$$c_{X',Y'}(f\otimes g)=(T(g)\otimes T(f))c_{T(X),T(Y)}.$$

(For simplicity, we may also assume that $T$ acts on objects as identity.)

So, this is not a braiding? Is there a canonical way, how to construct an actual braiding out of this or it need not exist at all?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

A braiding is not *just* a natural isomorphism between the functors $(-\otimes=)$ and $(=\otimes-)$. It is a natural isomorphism satisfying important coherence relations which one should always rigorously check before we call something a braiding (I have a vendetta against abuse of the isomorphism symbol in category theory literature).

The equation $c_{X',Y'}(f\otimes g)=(f\otimes g)c_{X,Y}$ is not correct in general. Let's denote by $\otimes'$ the twisted functor $(a,b)\mapsto b\otimes a$. We want $c_{X,Y}:\otimes(X,Y)\to\otimes'(X,Y)$ to be a natural transformation, so that we want $c_{X',Y'}\circ(\otimes(f,g))=(\otimes'(f,g))c_{X,Y}$ i.e. $c_{X',Y'}(f\otimes g)=\color{red}{(g\otimes f)}c_{X,Y}$.

Your autoequivalence statement does not make sense unless $T$ really is the identity on objects, since the RHS runs $T(X)\otimes T(Y)\to T(Y')\otimes T(X')$ but the LHS runs $X\otimes Y\to Y'\otimes X'$. To remove the asymmetry with $T$ on one side but not on the other, I think the "correct question to ask" should involve applying $T$ to make the domains and codomains align (requiring equality of objects is unnatural in category theory):

> Can we get a natural isomorphism $(-\otimes=)\cong(=\otimes-)$ if there exist arrows (isomorphisms) $c_{A,B}:A\otimes B\to B\otimes A$ satisfying: $$T(c_{X',Y'}(f\otimes g))\mu_{X,Y}=\mu_{Y',X'}(T(g)\otimes T(f))c_{T(X),T(Y)}:T(X)\otimes T(Y)\to T(Y'\otimes X')$$Where $\mu:T(-)\otimes T(=)\implies T(-\otimes =)$ is the monoidal multiplication associated to the monoidal functor $T$?

My hunch is that the answer is no. For a little while I hit this equation with the antiequivalence and the natural isomorphism maps but really only succeeded in converting the equation above for $T$ into an analogous one with its antiequivalence. I suspect a positive answer could be possible under extra conditions, if you found a useful coherence relation between $c_{TX,TY}$ and $T(c_{X,Y})$.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not the only condition, sure. You are right, it makes sense only if the equivalence is identity on objects. As I am thinking about it, it seems to me that a normal braiding should exist if and only if the autoequivalence is inner since you can somewhat realize it by composing the strange braiding with an inverse of the normal one or so.